# DELPHI 10.3 - loop while until key pressed little problem

Tags: loops, delphi, while-loop, key, keypress

Goodmorning everyone,
I wrote a very simple application in which I have to wait for the user to press a key (for example F2) to continue processing. The waiting cycle for pressing the button works perfectly, but the problem I need help with is this: if, during the waiting cycle of pressing a button, I click on another application, my application loses focus and I can no longer regain control. 
Even if I click on any part of my application, the caption of the form always remains gray, the application remains waiting for the pressure of a key and if I press the desired key obviously nothing happens. 
How do I regain control of my application? I thought I would put instructions like SetFocus, StayOnTop, SetForegroundWindow, ... etc inside the while loop, to ALWAYS keep my application active but I was unable to combine anything ... The code is as follows:

```
var

  Form2: TForm2;
  mkey: word; 

implementation

{$R *.dfm} 

procedure TForm2.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);

begin

  label1.Visible:= false;

  mkey:= 0;

  keyPreview:= true;

  while mkey <> VK_F2 do begin

    label1.Visible:= true;

    label1.Caption:= datetimetostr(now);   // for example

    application.ProcessMessages;

  end;

  label1.Visible:= false;

end; 

procedure TForm2.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);

begin

  mkey:= key;

end;

end.
```

Comment: The OS is event driven. Do not wait in a loop, instead use the key press event to execute the next step in your task. Look for a state machine.

Comment: Did not trace but obviously one part of the problem is that WM_ACTIVATE never returns. Default window procedure should set the focus to your form, which, thanks to your loop, never called (or returns). .. Since you don't have the focus, you can't press F2 or any other key.

Answer (score 9):

I don't want to sound harsh, but, unfortunately, your design is fundamentally flawed.

As indicated in the comments, graphical Windows applications -- and, in particular, VCL applications -- are event driven. (Under the hood, this works thanks to message pumps, but VCL developers most often need not be concerned with such details. In particular, new Delphi developers typically don't know about the underlying message pumps, and can still write high-quality GUI applications if they are careful.)

So, for instance, waiting for a key to be pressed using an explicit loop is almost always wrong. Also, having to call `Application.ProcessMessages` is a clear sign of a (major) design flaw (in many cases, but not this one, the solution is to add a new thread). Finally, if a seemingly basic task causes issues that you need to add code to work around (like `SetFocus`), you should always ask yourself if there is a better solution.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but the following example might be helpful.

1. Create a new VCL application. Give the main form a good name, like `frmMain` using the Object Inspector. In the code editor, add a private field `FStarted: Boolean` to the form class. Since this is a field in a class, it's initialized (since it's a `Boolean`, to `False`).¹

   ```
     private
       FStarted: Boolean;
   ```
2. Add a `TLabel` control to the form. Set its name to `lblMainText` using the Object Inspector. Sets its font to something visually pleasing², and its caption to `Press F2 to begin.`
3. In the form's `OnKeyDown` event handler, add the following code³:

   ```
   procedure TfrmMain.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
     Shift: TShiftState);
   begin
     if (Key = VK_F2) and not FStarted then
     begin
       MessageBeep(MB_ICONASTERISK);
       lblMainText.Caption := 'Let''s get to work!';
       FStarted := True;
     end;
   end;
   ```
4. Run the application.

[image: Screenshot of the application immediately after startup.]

After pressing F2:

[image: Screenshot of the application after F2 has been pressed.]

Notice that pressing F2 again doesn't do anything; you have already "started" the system.

Obviously, this small answer won't teach you all you need to know to write VCL applications. It only touches some 0.1% of what you need to know. To learn more, I strongly recommend buying a good book about Delphi programming (in particular, about writing Win32 applications in Delphi).

¹ In Delphi, global variables and class members are initialized (to `0`, `0.0`, `False`, `nil`, etc.). However, local variables are never initialized (unless they are of managed types).

² `Segoe UI` is a good choice, according to the [Microsoft Windows User Interface Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-fonts). In fact, you can use this font for the *form* itself; then all child controls will inherit this font setting automatically.

³ This will only work if the form itself has focus (and, for instance, not a child control). To make this work even if a child control has focus, my best suggestion is to use a `TActionList`. They are really useful.